Any way to get the creation date of a token programatically?
I want to get the creation date of a token, given that I have the mint address. Right now I'm looping backwards by approximately 1000tx/s using "getSignaturesForAddress". This method is extremely slow, especially for tokens with high volume.
I was also considering using Dune Analytics to get this data, but for some reason their website isn't working at the moment.
Is there any faster solution to find creation date?
EDIT - Possible Solution (Did not try yet): if you can get the creation date of the Raydium liquidity pool, you can just go backwards in time from there. Someone else provided me this link to find the liquidity pool creation time:
https://gist.github.com/rubpy/f77b025771928882ae824531716355ee
